# workaround for missing pm3d corners2color feature in gnuplot

Tags: image, gnuplot, heatmap

As written in the [manual of Gnuplot at page 136](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.6/gnuplot.pdf#page=136),

> Because the pm3d algorithm does not extend the colored surface outside
>   the range of the input data points, the 'c' coloring options will
>   result in pixels along two edges of the grid not contributing to the
>   color of any quadrangle. For example, applying the pm3d algorithm to
>   the 4x4 grid of data points in script demo/pm3d.dem (please have a
>   look) produces only (4-1)x(4-1)=9 colored rectangles.

So if I would like to plot a 4x4 pixel sized image, I can't do it in this way without missing the 4th column and row. (I would like not to modify the file.) Is there an efficent workaround for this problem?

Comment: Do you really need pm3d, i.e. do you need some kind of interpolation, or is a `plot ... with image` what you actually want? For this, see my (lenghty) answer to [gnuplot matrix or palette using one line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18297966/2604213)

Comment: The `plot ... with image` satisfies my requirements. If you would write an answer I could accept it. This question is important and not trivial to use this solution because as I see it is an improvement in gnuplot since 4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To plot a `4x4` image which shows exactly the color rectangles specified in the data file, the `splot ... with pm3d` is not suited. For this one can use the `image` plotting style. The `pm3d` mode must be used e.g when the grid points are not equidistant, or for a 3D representation.

Taking the following file `data.dat`

```
1 6 8 3
2 5 4 4
9 1 1 2
5 4 3 8
```

a more or less minimal script would be

```
set autoscale fix
set xtics 1 out
set ytics 1 out
plot 'data.dat' matrix with image t ''
```

The result for `set terminal pngcairo` is:

[image]

The terminal must support plotting `with image`, this is the case for the most, but not for all (e.g. `pstricks` does not). In that case one would need to use `with image failsafe`.