# How to plot time graph in gnuplot

Tags: time, graph, gnuplot

I have a data file of format

```
time x-axis y-axis val1 val2
0    1      1      0.3   0.5
0    1      2      0.3   0.5
0    2      1      0.3   0.5
0    2      2      0.3   0.5
1    1      1      0.6   0.3
1    1      2      0.6   0.3
1    2      1      0.6   0.3
1    2      2      0.6   0.3
```

I wish to draw gif/video of val1 at xy given above with various time steps. How can i do that?
I googled and found various solutions not matching my requirement. Please help.

Comment: It depends a bit on how you want to vizualize your data. See e.g my answer to [gnuplot matrix or palette using one line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18297966/2604213) for an example with a `2x2` matrix which changes over time. Would this fit? It uses `terminal gif animate` to create the video.

Comment: Or, have a look [here](http://users.softlab.ece.ntua.gr/~ttsiod/gnuplotStreaming.html) on animated plotting in Gnuplot.