# With gnuplot, how to plot a vector (i.e. 1xN or Nx1 matrix) as image?

Tags: image, matrix, plot, vector, gnuplot

How to plot a vector (i.e. 1xN or Nx1 matrix) as image?
I have no problem to plot 2x2 matrices, as follows:

```
plot '-' matrix with image
1 2 
3 4 
e
```

However, the following two examples with 2x1 and 1x2 matrices fail:

```
plot '-' matrix with image
1 
3 
e

plot '-' matrix with image
1 2
e
```

For both, I get the warning:

```
Image grid must be at least 4 points (2 x 2).
```

and nothing is rendered.

Is there another way to plot the Nx1 or 1xN matrices, so that they are rendered similar to the 2x2 matrix?

"[gnuplot matrix or palette using one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290772/gnuplot-matrix-or-palette-using-one-line)" might be in parts related. However, the problem there is much more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way which works also with `1xN` and `Nx1` matrices.
It is using plotting style `with boxxyerror`. It works for gnuplot 5.x and with files instead of datablocks probably also for gnuplot 4.x.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.0)

```
### plot small matrix
reset session

$Data1 <<EOD
 1  2
 3  4
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
 1
 3
EOD

$Data3 <<EOD
 1 2
EOD

set size ratio -1
set style fill solid 1.0
set key noautotitle
set cbrange[1:4]
set xtics  1
set ytics  1
set cbtics 1

set multiplot layout 1,3
    plot $Data1 u 1:2:(0.5):(0.5):3 matrix w boxxy lc palette z
    plot $Data2 u 1:2:(0.5):(0.5):3 matrix w boxxy lc palette z
    plot $Data3 u 1:2:(0.5):(0.5):3 matrix w boxxy lc palette z
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**This answer assumes gnuplot version 6**

Sort of.  A plot `with image` will not accept a 1-dimensional array, but you can create a 1-dimensional pixmap and plot that instead.  The example below is probably more complicated than needed, but it shows the relationships between the palette, a colormap, a pixmap, and a data array.  All of these are basically 1-dimensional arrays; however their syntax and use in the program varies.

```
# Create a 1x4 colormap named M1x4

set palette maxcolors 4
set colormap new M1x4

# Restore palette mapping that will be used for a plot
# Note: maxcolors 0 resets to the default for the current terminal
#       cbrange sets the range of values the palette will map to
set palette maxcolors 0
set cbrange [0:512]

# Unfortunately the palette values are not recalculated until something
# is plotted to use them, so make a dummy plot to force the recalcuation.
set table $junk
plot x lc palette
unset table

# Reload the entries in our named colormap with the corresponding
# mappings of data values into the current palette.
array DATA = [ 15,  127, 415, 333 ]
M1x4[1] = palette( DATA[1] )
M1x4[2] = palette( DATA[2] )
M1x4[3] = palette( DATA[3] )
M1x4[4] = palette( DATA[4] )
print M1x4

# Now define a pixmap object to be plotted
set pixmap 1 colormap M1x4 size 4, 1
set pixmap 1 at graph 0.5, graph 0.5

# Plot anything you like; the pixmap object will be part of the plot
# For the purpose of illustration, we choose something that will show
# the palette mapping in the color box.
plot x lc palette
```

[image]

**Work-around for version 5 that does not use pixmaps**

To work around the need for height and width both greater than 1, you could add a dummy row of values that contain NaN.  These will be transparent when plotted `with image`, although they do affect the scaling:

```
plot '-' matrix with image
15 127 415 333
NaN NaN NaN NaN
e
```

[image]